# Rails doesn't throw an error when filling unexisted field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I've created a model User with fields name, email and password. In the new.html.erb file in the loop

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

<%= f.password_field :wtf %>
```

and this form works only for password_field, if I write

`<%= f.text_field :wtf %>`
it throws an error that User doesn't have such method 'wtf'

Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You could make :wtf a virtual attribute in the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :wtf
end
```

If you aren't defining a form for a model then you could use [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) instead of `form_for`: